# unique urls for products in an e-comm website PHP

Tags: php

I'm not sure if this is a stupid question or not but I am creating an e-comm website at the moment which I would like to make as professional and secure as possible.

I want each product to have its own unique url for accessibility purposes but I'm not sure how to do this as right now I am using a **GET** variable to create unique pages dynamically.

It looks like this:

```
example.com/product?product=1
```

As you can see, this isn't a very accessible way to separate products (Using unique ID's) and it's also not very safe in terms of using with a database.

What I am wanting the unique url's to be like:

```
example.com/products/unique-product-name
```

I want to be able to use url's like this while still keeping the php simple for database use.

How can I do this quickly and simply without having to create individual pages for each product??

Comment: Use URL rewriting. What server are you using? Apache? You will also have to create unique slugs for the products (the `unique-product-name` things).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I'm using Apache, yes.

Comment: Here is a [rewrite guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) for Apache. [This article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) by SmashingMagazine is a quite good introduction to URL rewriting. You can also search Google for something like "[apache url rewriting](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+url+rewriting)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to have a *unique* alias field for each product in your DB, so that you can access your product via `GET` method like this:

`www.example.com/product.php?alias=YOUR-ALIAS`

And then you can use *mod_rewrite* to map `www.example.com/products/YOUR-ALIAS` to the above link.

In order to do this, you have to create a text file called `.htaccess` (NOTE: there is no file extension, the fullname of the file is `.htaccess`) with the following rules in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)$  /product.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

You then have to upload the `.htaccess` and `product.php` files to the root of your server.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I know the files are able to communicate because I am able to use rewrites to get rid of file extensions. I don't understand what the problem might be.

Comment: Please take a look at the log file of your Apache, what HTTP status code do you get when accessing `www.example.com/products/YOUR-PRODUCT`?

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404

Comment: Is `product.php` at the root of your server? If so, this is very likely that `mod_rewrite` is not working, and your server failed to find something at `www.example.com/products/YOUR-PRODUCT`. If this is the case, please confirm whether `mod_rewrite` is working by uploading a fresh `.htaccess` file with ONLY the two lines of rules in my answer, and a `product.php` file to the root of your server.

Comment: Interestingly I have tested the same instance on 3 servers all running apache and received 3 completely different results. On one of the servers it works, the other 2 don't but they output different errors. One outputs the error I showed you before, and the other recognizes what file I'm looking for but somehow thinks it doesn't exist? It's a curious thing

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue and got the same instance working on all 3 of my testing servers. For 2 of them to work I simply had to take the leading forward slash out of chiwangc's answer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)$  product.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

I'm not 100% sure why this is the case only some of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I already worked on for that type of many project.
Please add in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    products.php?alias=$1    [NC,L]
```

and used anchor tag on like this

```
<a href"products/<?php echo $variable['alias']; ?>">product name</a>
```